# Javascript showing the function text instead of printing value on screen

Tags: javascript

```
function hex(x,y,side,isLast,color)
{//Hex object constructor.

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.side = side;
    this.isLast = isLast;
    this.color = color;

    function multiply()
    {
        return this.x * this.y;
    }

    this.multiply = multiply;
}


var hexagon = new hex(22,22,20,0,1);

document.write(hexagon.multiply);
```

When loading index.htm, results that writes on screen the function instead of the returning value:

function multiply() { return this.x * this.y; }

:(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot the ():

```
document.write(hexagon.multiply());
```

If you don't use (), Javascript will treat `multiply` as a variable and write out it contents - in this case, the code of the function.

Comment: De nada! (Guessing locale from last name - forgive me if I'm wrong ;)

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure that your javascript code is in `<script>` and `</script>` tags.  So, it might read:

```
<html><head><script type="text/javascript">
function hex(x,y,side,isLast,color)
{//Hex object constructor.

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.side = side;
    this.isLast = isLast;
    this.color = color;

    function multiply()
    {
        return this.x * this.y;
    }

    this.multiply = multiply;
}


var hexagon = new hex(22,22,20,0,1);

document.write(hexagon.multiply)
</script>
<body>
<!--Content here-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good thought but not the point here I think - if it were, it would show the whole function and not only multiply().